# SFML Window::getPosition() and setPosition do not agree in coordinates

Tags: c++, sfml

Going through the SFML tutorial I tried to write a small code example that slides the window to the right over time, it acted in a way that I didn't expect (the window slid all the way to the bottom). Here's a minimal example that has the window moving despite sticking the exact same coordinates that `getPosition` spits out into `setPosition`

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Clock.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Time.hpp>

int main(){
  sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Aydin's Window");

  window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(10, 10));
  sf::Clock clock;

  while(window.isOpen()){
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
      if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }

    sf::Time elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();
    if(elapsed > sf::milliseconds(100)){
      sf::Vector2i pos = window.getPosition();
      window.setPosition(pos);
      clock.restart();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

One would expect this code to keep the window where it is, but instead it slides to the right and downwards on my machine. I had a friend run the same code. On his machine it slides to the left and upwards. What is going on?

edit: when I create the window without decorations (sf::Style::None) the windows stays where it is. I'm guessing one of `getPosition` or `setPosition` is getting offset by the title bar and the other is not.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, window position grabs coordinates from your underlying operating system to work. Anything inside the SFML window will take the bottom left as an origin point. But when it comes to window position that is calculated by the OS.

Comment: If you believe there's a bug in SFML you should discuss it on [SFML forum](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums). Don't forget to read the etiquette on how to report bugs -- this includes for example mentioning which version of SFML you're using as well as the OS you're running on.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a problem I had and found this post, but after reading your question, I am not sure, if you have the same problem as I had.
Nevertheless I think, you have to center your sf::View

```
sf::Event event;
while (window.pollEvent(event)) 
if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
    {
        float width = static_cast<float>(event.size.width);
        float height = static_cast<float>(event.size.height);
        window.setView(sf::View(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, width, height)));
    }
```

Hope that helps.